# Fill EditText in new Dialog with values from ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Hey i am trying to fill an `EditText` in a new Dialog with values from a `ListView`. The problem is that i get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object
```

I put a Toast on the values obtained from the `ListView` and it works, it returns the specific value.
When i try to call `.setText(ValueFromListView)` it gives the error and i don't understand why. Can anyone help me with this?
Here is the code:

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, final long id) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setTitle("Edit item...");
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_edit_delete);
    dialog.show();

    Button button_UPDATE = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_dialog_edit_delete_button_UPDATE);
    Button button_CANCEL = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_dialog_edit_delete_button_CANCEL);
    Button button_DELETE = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_dialog_edit_delete_button_DELETE);

    // GET PRODUCT REFERENCES
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String productName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_PRODUCT));
    String productPrice = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_PRICE));
    String productType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_TYPE));
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, productName + " " + productPrice + " " + productType, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

    EditText prodField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.custom_dialog_edit_delete__productName);
    prodField.setText(productName); // This is the line that i get the null pointer exception
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EditText` is available inside your dialog so you must give reference of yout dialog when creating object of `EditText`.

```
EditText prodField = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_dialog_edit_delete__productName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
EditText prodField = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_dialog_edit_delete__productName);
prodField.setText(productName);
```

//